# Fill blanks in a column in Excel above and below

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel, using only formulas, with data looking as follows (where n/a is blank):

```
121 0 n/a
121 1 n/a
121 2 Y>
121 3 n/a
121 4 Y
121 5 n/a
122 0 Y
122 1 n/a
123 0 n/a
124 0 n/a
124 1 Y
```

I would like the 3th column to always show Y for the rows where the second column shows 0, if there's a Y for any with the same number in column 1 in column3.

So as follows:

```
121 0 Y
121 1 n/a
121 2 Y
121 3 n/a
121 4 Y
121 5 n/a
122 0 Y
122 1 n/a
123 0 n/a
124 0 Y
124 1 Y
```

Alternatively, filling all values up with Y for each number in column 1 for which there's at least one Y in column 3.

Comment: And how are the original Y values produced?  Does the third column have a formula?

Comment: It's very hard to understand your question - your condition for column 3 seems to be based on the content of column 3. Can you rewrite your requirements so the conditions for column 3 are solely based on the values in columns 1 and 2?

Comment: Hi Tim, the values in column C are based on another variable in another column.

Comment: Hey Simon, the computed data would indeed need to end up in a (temporary) 4th column, as per Jerry's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put a formula into cells in column C because you are using column C in your formula - it would cause a circular reference.  Instead paste this array formula into column D1 (don't forget to press shift-control-enter to enter it because it is an array formula) and then copy and paste it to all the other cells in column D that have data in columns A through C:

```
=IF((SUM(IF((A:A=A1)*(C:C="Y"),1,0))>0)*(B1=0),"Y",IF(ISBLANK(C1),"",C1))
```

For faster calculations: assuming your data is in A1:C11 change it to:

```
=IF((SUM(IF((A1:A11=A1)*(C1:C11="Y"),1,0))>0)*(B1=0),"Y",IF(ISBLANK(C1),"",C1))
```

What this does is say:

```
if a cell in column A equals A1 and a cell in column C is "Y" then add 1 to the
array otherwise add 0.  then if the sum of the array is > 0 and B1 equals 0 then
return "Y" otherwise return C1 (or "" if C1 is blank)
```

That gives this result:

```
 A     B    C    D
121    0         Y
121    1
121    2    Y    Y
121    3
121    4    Y    Y
121    5
122    0    Y    Y
122    1
123    0
124    0         Y
124    1    Y    Y
```

Comment: Great Jerry, this works. It causes a very long "Calculating" step each time I filter the data or do anything if I keep that column in the spreadsheet like this, but copying the generated values takes care of that.

Comment: @user3538571 change the A:A and C:C to be the range of your data.  I'll edit the answer.